# Как правильно использовать do_shortcode с ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, shortcode

На сайте нужно разместить слайдер один для ПК, второй для мобильных устройств. Изначально был один слайдер и добавлял его с помощью

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1"]'); ?>
```

Но добавлять сразу два слайдера через шорткод, а потом скрывать с помощью CSS как то не хочется. Думал решить это с помощью ajax, но тут я валенок. Помогите решить проблемку.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: По уму надо не два слайдера, а самом слайдере при выводе картинок надо учитывать "адаптивность"

Comment: для пк картинки очень широкие и на телефонах не видно деталей, то сделали другой слайдер с другой соотношением сторон. в данном случае нужно еще один слайдер

Comment: Так в самом слайдере показывать нужные картинки (др. размеров/соотношений) и пр.  А насчёт "по уму" я может и немного погорячился. Это один из правильных вариантов, но не единственный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение данной проблемы. В WordPress уже есть встроенный обработчик ajax запросов, чтобы вызвать его нужно в файле данной темы functions.php прописать такую функцию

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_slider1', 'slider_function' ); // wp_ajax_{ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПАРАМЕТРА ACTION!!}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_slider1', 'slider_function' );  // wp_ajax_nopriv_{ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ACTION!!}
// первый хук для авторизованных, второй для не авторизованных пользователей

function slider_function(){

    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );

    die; // даём понять, что обработчик закончил выполнение
}
```

В моем случае вместо шорткода я заменил на сайтбар, который можно спокойно редактировать и через админку у виджетах, если нужно вставить то вместо вызова сайтбара нужно заменить

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
```

на вызов самого шорткода

```
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
```

А далее в нужном файле делаем уже ajax запрос
В данном случае он выглядит вот таким образом

```
<script>
    jQuery( function ($) {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action : 'slider2'
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ajaxLoadSlider').html(data);
                }
            })
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action : 'slider1'
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ajaxLoadSlider').html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

Где:

- `url` - путь к файлу обработчика ajax запросов
- `type` - тип запроса `GET`, `POST` и т.д.
- `data` - какие значения должны передаться, оно должно совпадать с последним словом в строке `add_action( 'wp_ajax_XXXXXX' )`
- `beforeSend` - что должно происходить когда идет обработка запроса
- `success` - что должно происходить после завершения обработки

П.С. Надеюсь нормально все прописал.